# Python TypeError when attempting to pass parameters to unittest subclass

Tags: python, unit-testing, subclass

I'm attempting to pass parameters to unittest subclass methods.  Please forgive my ignorance - I've only started coding in Python a few days ago.  I could obviously just hardcode the parameters in the subclass itself but that would eliminate its reuse with other username/password combos.  When I run run_tests.py below, I get the error "TypeError: runTest() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)".

Here is run_tests.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from testcases import login


def my_suite():

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest (login.Login().runTest("username1", "password1", "page title"))
    return suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(my_suite())
```

Here is testcases/basetestcase.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class BaseTestCase (unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "http://website"

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

Here is testcases/login.py

```
import common_page_elements
from basetestcase import BaseTestCase

class Login (BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(username, password, verification):
        """ Test logging in. """
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_username).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_username).send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_password).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_password).send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name(common_page_elements.button_submit).click()        

        self.assertTrue(verification in self.driver.title)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `runTest` has become a class method, you'll have to include the `self` argument:

```
class Login (BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(self, username, password, verification):
                ^^^^
```